# Checkbox runtime error if before textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I coded an app with several textview and checkbox.
Now I'm trying to add a new checkbox:

if I add it before a textview I get a runtime error,
if i add after it, there are no runtime error.

CODE:
In this way it does work

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInstructions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/impostazioni_19"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbPowerSavingMode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/light_sens_9" >
</CheckBox>
```

In this way it doesn't work:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbPowerSavingMode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/light_sens_9" >
</CheckBox>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInstructions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/impostazioni_19"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

What's the problem?

```
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.android.smartscreenoffpro/it.android.smartscreenoffpro.ActivityImpostazioni}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at it.android.smartscreenoffpro.ActivityImpostazioni.onCreate(ActivityImpostazioni.java:51)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
03-25 10:18:25.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1546):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post line 51 of ActivityImpostazioni.java?

Comment: cbPowerSavingMode = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbPowerSavingMode);

Comment: After compiling source several time started working...

Comment: what type of cbPowerSavingMode variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and recompiling will solve the issue.
Below is the step required for cleaning the project.
Goto Project Window and click Clean... menu item. A dialog will come which will show you the project to clean